# plotting solid of revolution contained between

Tags: maple

I want to plot cylinder contained between planes z=x+1/2 and z= -x-1/2.This cylinder should have radius equal to one.

I tried to find something in maple help. But my work was done at this moment :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th2Ak.jpg)

So as you see, i get my cylinder with the radius 1 but I dont know how to make this contained between planes z=x+1/2 and z= -x-1/2.

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by, "contained between planes z=x+1/2 and z=-x-1/2".

Do you mean between x+1/2 and x-1/2?

```
restart;
C:=plots:-cylinderplot(0.5,theta=0..2*Pi,z=0.5..0.5+1/sqrt(2),
                       style=surface):
rotC:=plottools:-rotate(C,-3*Pi/4,[[0,0.5,0.5],[0,-0.5,0.5]]):

plots:-display(
  rotC,
  plot3d([x-1/2,x+1/2],x=-0.5..1,y=-0.75..0.75,
         style=surface,color=gray,transparency=0.5),
  scaling=constrained, view=-0.5..1
);
```

[image]